# Java UI thread blocked - Out of Memory error

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading

In my application, I get messages every second, which contains the altitude, speed and heading. Each time, I get the message, I need to generate a symbol (jpg) and show it in UI of the desktop application. Below is the code I used. For some reason, as soon as below code is integrated into application, I keep getting OutOfMemory error.

In order to get rid of it, I put the instance creation of below class and call to createSymbol in a separate thread and made svg to jpg conversion into separate thread. Even then the issue is not resolved. I am thinking, since this code is executed every second, loading of javascript library milsymbol.js in memory causes this issue.

Coming to my questions, is my understanding correct? or what could be the problem you think?

If my understanding is correct, is there a way, I can load the library once in the memory and everytime, I can just refer to already loaded library to call a function on it?

Do you think of any improvements with respect to the below code?

```
public class SymbolCreation {

    private static final Logger log =
            Logger.getLogger( UAVSymbolCreation.class );

    int altitude;
    int heading;
    int speed;

    public SymbolCreation(int altitude, int speed, int heading) {
        this.altitude = altitude;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public void createSymbol() {

        synchronized(this) {
            File milSymbolLib = new File("config/4586controller/milsymbol.js");

            if(milSymbolLib.exists()) {
                try {
                    Reader libraryReader = new FileReader(milSymbolLib);
                    ScriptEngine scriptEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
                    scriptEngine.eval(libraryReader);
                    SymbolCreation symbolCreation = this;
                    scriptEngine.put("symbolCreation",symbolCreation);
                    scriptEngine.eval("function run(symbolCreation){var altitude = symbolCreation.getAltitude(); "
                            + "var speedVal = symbolCreation.getSpeed(); "
                            + "var heading = symbolCreation.getHeading();"
                            + "symbolCreation.createSymbolSVG(new ms.Symbol('SFA-MFQ--------',{size:20, altitudeDepth:altitude, speed: speedVal , direction: heading}).asSVG());} run(symbolCreation);");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ScriptException se) {
                    se.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 
        }

    }

    public void createSymbolSVG(String svgStr) {

        synchronized(this) {
            boolean fileCreated = false;
            File svgFile = new File("config/4586controller/symbol.svg");
            if(!svgFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    fileCreated = svgFile.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                fileCreated = true;
            }

            try {
                if(fileCreated) {
                    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(svgStr);
                    Path svgFilePath = Paths.get(svgFile.getPath());
                    Files.write(svgFilePath, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

                    //Conversion will happen on an individual thread - COMMENTED OUT 
                    convertSVGToJPEG(svgFile);

                }
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void convertSVGToJPEG(final File svgFile) {
        synchronized(this) {
            Runnable svgToJPEGConversion = new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    try {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //NOw convert svg to jpg
                        String svg_URI_input = svgFile.toURI().toString();
                        TranscoderInput input_svg_image = new TranscoderInput(svg_URI_input);        
                        //Step-2: Define OutputStream to JPG file and attach to TranscoderOutput
                        File jpgFile = new File("config/4586controller/uav.jpg");
                        if(jpgFile.exists()) {
                            jpgFile.createNewFile();
                        }

                        OutputStream jpg_ostream = new FileOutputStream(jpgFile);
                        TranscoderOutput output_jpg_image = new TranscoderOutput(jpg_ostream);              
                        // Step-3: Create JPEGTranscoder and define hints
                        JPEGTranscoder my_converter = new JPEGTranscoder();
                        my_converter.addTranscodingHint(JPEGTranscoder.KEY_QUALITY,new Float(.9));
                        // Step-4: Write output
                        my_converter.transcode(input_svg_image, output_jpg_image);
                        // Step 5- close / flush Output Stream
                        jpg_ostream.flush();
                        jpg_ostream.close();       
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (TranscoderException te) {
                        te.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }

            };

            Thread imageConversionThread = new Thread(svgToJPEGConversion);
            imageConversionThread.start();
        }

    }

    public int getAltitude() {
        return altitude;
    }

    public int getHeading() {
        return heading;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using `synchronized(this)` everywhere instead of just making the methods synchronized?

Comment: Thats because I want to apply lock on the class instead of instance. because for every thread I create a new instance. because, i cannot make different instances to act on the method. I want the symbol creation to be sequential as the message comes through

Comment: But `this` is not a class, it's the current instance. It's just the longer way of writing `public synchronized void createSymbolSVG(..`.

Comment: Would you recommend, create a static lock for that class and use that for synchronized block?

Comment: I would recommend you don't try to mash things together without understanding what they do. Why do you generate symbols when you receive a message? Why don't you generate them beforehand?

Comment: @Kayaman because symbols are dynamic and based out of parameters from an incoming message. The symbol should represent the parameters in the UI

Comment: How many different symbols do you expect to have? There's a lot of things you could fix here, but they're design issues. I don't really see a compelling reason for synchronization here either. You could probably use caching for the symbols (not to mention the scripts), as well as only create a new image if things have changed.

Comment: @Kayaman Even I am thinking of removing threads once I came to know about close issue. May be caching might help little bit but I dont think I can 100% result would be there as the altitude and speed might be mostly the same, there is a possibility heading could be changed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`java.io.FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) class uses streams to read the file.
Your code never calls the [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#close()) method inherited from the `InputStreamReader` class on the `libraryReader` object.

You can add a `finally` block in order to close the reader or use the [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement - available from Java8  - since the `FileReader` class implements the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface.

---

It's also better to check how many threads are alive at the same time, since each calls to the `convertSVGToJPEG` method creates a new thread.

Comment: @Kayaman I would also appreciate Kayaman's effort in working out the problem in details

Comment: @nathan Appreciate the effort who found the answer but presented incorrectly